# xarray.align propagate NaNs?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm aligning multiple datasets (model and observations) and I thought it would make a lot of sense if `xarray.align` had a method to propagate NaNs/missing data in one dataset to the others. For now, I'm using `xr.dataset.where` in combination with `np.isfinite`, but especially my attempt to generalize this for more than two arrays feels a bit tricky. Is there a better way to do this?

```
a = xr.DataArray(np.arange(10).astype(float))
b = xr.DataArray(np.arange(10).astype(float))
a[[4, 5]] = np.nan
print(a.values)
print(b.values)

>> [ 0.  1.  2.  3. nan nan  6.  7.  8.  9.]
>> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]


# Default behaviour
c, d = xr.align(a, b)
print(c.values)
print(d.values)

>> [ 0.  1.  2.  3. nan nan  6.  7.  8.  9.]
>> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]

# Desired behaviour
e, f = xr.align(a.where(np.isfinite(b)), b.where(np.isfinite(a)))
print(e.values)
print(f.values)

>> [ 0.  1.  2.  3. nan nan  6.  7.  8.  9.]
>> [ 0.  1.  2.  3. nan nan  6.  7.  8.  9.]

# Attempt to generalize for multiple arrays
c = b.copy()
c [[1, -1]] = np.nan
def align_better(*dataarrays):
    allvalid = np.all(np.array([np.isfinite(x) for x in dataarrays]), axis=0)
    return xr.align(*[da.where(allvalid) for da in dataarrays])

g, h, i = align_better(a, b, c)
print(g.values)
print(h.values)
print(i.values)

>> [ 0. nan  2.  3. nan nan  6.  7.  8. nan]
>> [ 0. nan  2.  3. nan nan  6.  7.  8. nan]
>> [ 0. nan  2.  3. nan nan  6.  7.  8. nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [xarray docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.align.html):

> Given any number of Dataset and/or DataArray objects, returns new objects with aligned indexes and dimension sizes.
>
> Array from the aligned objects are suitable as input to mathematical operators, because along each dimension they have the same index and size.
>
> Missing values (if `join != 'inner'`) are filled with `NaN`.

Nothing about this function deals with the values in the arrays, just the dimensions and coordinates. This function is used for setting up arrays for operations against each other.

If your desired behavior is a function that returns `NaN` for all arrays where any arrays are `NaN`, your `align_better` function seems like a decent way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The function in my initial attempt was slow because dataarrays were casted to numpy arrays. In this modified version, I first align the datasets. Then I can safely use the `.values` method. This is much faster.

```
def align_better(*dataarrays):
    """ Align datasets and propage NaNs """
    aligned = xr.align(*dataarrays)
    allvalid = np.all(np.asarray([np.isfinite(x).values for x in aligned]), axis=0)
    return [da.where(allvalid) for da in aligned]
```